# pandas : an array of Series by reducing a large Serie

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I've got one Serie of int, like this one :

```
ages = pd.DataFrame(np.array([100, 107,99,98,65,45,32,18,66,69, 74,83,81,67, 101, 94, 52,90]), columns=["age"])
```

My goal is create several Series in an array. Each serie should include only the values in an interval.

For example, array_series[0] will return :

```
    age
0   100
1   107
2   99
3   98
4   101
5   94
6   90
```

array_series[1] will return :

```
    age
0   83
1   81
```

etc...

I've tried (and failed) two options :

- first, an if/else statement in a for loop :

  ```
  array_series = []

  for step in range(90,60,-10):
      if ages["age"] >= step:
          # selection when the age is higher than 90, or between 80 and 90, 70 and 80 and 60 and 70
          df_interval = ages[ages["age"] >= step]
          # then we add this Serie in the array
          array_series.append(df_interval)
          # finally we delete the values of the new Serie in the larger one to avoid duplicates
          ages = pd.concat([ages, df_interval, df_interval]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
      else:
          # final Serie (age < 60)
          df_interval = ages[ages["age"] < step]
          array_series.append(df_interval)
  ```

Long story short : ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

- So I looked for an alternative solution, and found np.where(), which seemed very elegant :

  ```
  for step in range(90,60,-10):
      df_interval = np.where(ages["age"] >= step, ages[ages["age"] >= step], ages[ages["age"] < step])
      array_series.append(df_interval)
  ```

Long story short, the comeback : ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (16,) (6,1) (10,1)

What other option should I consider ?

EDIT : the array have stricted intervals like these :
* array_series[0] : values higher than 90
* array_series[1] : values between 80 and 90
* array_series[2] : values between 70 and 80
* array_series[3] : values between 60 and 70
* array_series[4] : finally, values under 60

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is `pd.cut` and `groupby()`:

```
bins = pd.cut(ages['age'], bins=range(0,100))

for r, d in ages.groupby(bins)['age']:
    print(r)
    print(d)
```

Comment: Thanks Quang, I've tried, it worked but I'm not sure to understand well what happens...

Comment: You can search for `pd.cut` and `pd.DataFrame.groupby()` for details. You can also print `bins` and compare with your `ages['age']` and see what it does.

Comment: It would be clearer with bins=[0,60,70,80,90,120], but that's fine. Thanks